# So im newbie in this thing, i need to create random number everytime someone refresh the page

Tags: html, random, html-table, numbers

Here is my code, i dont know what to input to get random number in my table. Can anyone help please? I want the number to change whenever someone refresh the page. the number must have 5 digits.

```
<div>
  <br>
</div>
<div class="custd-container custd-bg">
  <table class="custd-bg" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="12" class="custd-18px custd-bg" style="text-align:center; border-bottom:2px solid #6f5d1a;">LUCKY NUMBER</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="custd-bg" rowspan="2" style="padding-left: 10px;"></td>
      <td class="custd-25px custd-center custd-bg" id="custangka">00001</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;" class="custd-15px custd-bg">LUCKY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-right: 10px;" class="custd-bg" colspan="3">
        <div class="progress21 progress-moved2 custd-bg" style="padding-left: 3px;">
          <div class="progress-bar21 custd-bg" style="padding-left: 3px;"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="custd-bg" style="text-align:left; border-right:2px solid #6f5d1a"></td>
      <td class="custd-bg" colspan="3" style="padding-left: 7px; padding-right: 10px;">
        <div class="progress31 progress-moved11 custd-bg1">
          <div class="progress-bar31 custd-bg"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="custd-bg" style="text-align:left; border-right:2px solid #6f5d1a"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

In order to create random numbers you will have to make use of JavaScript.
A random number with 5 digits can be generated and put into the div with id "custangka" like this:

```js
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) ) + min;
}
document.getElementById("custangka").innerHTML = getRndInteger(10000, 99999);
```

The code is partially taken from https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_random.asp.

Please be aware that this number is generated on the client side, so on the computer that is loading the page. This means that the client can control the number.